# Trying to draw a bar chart in D3 and I am not seeing the output

Tags: html, d3.js

I am learning D3  and trying to create a bar chart. I dont know why there is no output.

```js
var w = 300;
var h = 100;

var padding = 2;

var dataset = [5, 10, 20, 12, 19];

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr({
        x: function(d, i) {
            return i * w / dataset.length;
        },
        y: function(d) {
            return h - d;
        },
        width: function(d) {
            return (w / dataset.length) - padding;
        },
        height: function(d) {
            return d;
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: here is my link to the jsfiddle page https://jsfiddle.net/hvsuaccount/harya9eo/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using d3v4, which does not let you set multiple attributes with `selection.attr()`. This functionality was present in d3v3, but removed starting with d3v4.

With d3v4/5 you can either:

- use d3.selection-multi
- set attributes one at a time

To keep almost the same code as you have, you can import [d3.selection-multi](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi), this allows you to use `selection.attrs({})` (not `.attr`) to set multiple attributes at once:

```
.attrs({
    x: function(d, i) {
        return i * w / dataset.length;
    },
    y: function(d) {
        return h - d;
    },
    width: function(d) {
        return (w / dataset.length) - padding;
    },
    height: function(d) {
        return d;
    }
})
```

The module is not included in the base d3 library so you'll need to import it for this approach to work:

```js
var w = 300;
var h = 100;

var padding = 2;

var dataset = [5, 10, 20, 12, 19];

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attrs({
        x: function(d, i) {
            return i * w / dataset.length;
        },
        y: function(d) {
            return h - d;
        },
        width: function(d) {
            return (w / dataset.length) - padding;
        },
        height: function(d) {
            return d;
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.min.js"></script>
```

The other option is to use `selection.attr()` to set one attribute at a time, rather than all at once:

```js
var w = 300;
var h = 100;

var padding = 2;

var dataset = [5, 10, 20, 12, 19];

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x",function(d, i) {
            return i * w / dataset.length;
        })
    .attr("y",function(d) {
            return h - d;
        })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
            return (w / dataset.length) - padding;
        })
    .attr("height",function(d) {
            return d;
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```